# minimalistic digital 2-speed oscillator with 555

Tags: transistors, oscillator, frequency, 555, pulse

I'm trying to figure out how I can turn a schematic of a one-speed simple 555 astable multivibrator that's available everywhere on the internet to a digitally controlled astable multivibrator in which the output frequency changes depending on the digital input.

More specifically, I need such a circuit to make an elegant programmer because the chip needs a longer pulse for erase and shorter pulse for data writing. (I'm programming AT89C2051). So I want to use a 555 and a transistor along with a high-inpedance or logic low input to choose between a 1.2ms and 10ms delay between each pulse from Q in the 555.

Am I on the right track with the circuit I came up with that's shown below?

[image: circuit]

**EDIT**

Ok I included a full circuit.

[image: circuit2]

Yes I can program but I want to make life a little easier for myself considering my last circuit I made was a failure. Now with a few modifications I can make it function like an MS-DOS printer. that way, if my system completely screws up and all I'm left with is a boot disk with no hard drive then I can still use my circuit.

So my question remains the same. Am I on the right track with the 1st circuit shown?

Comment: This is silly.  Use a microcontroller already!

Comment: And how about accepting an answer or two?

Comment: Not accustomed to seeing "555" and "elegant" together.

Comment: I can only stress what Olin said (and that's usually a good thing!): this is something extremely easy with 1€ worth of microcontroller. You don't want to rely on the speed of some 1970's capacitor-charger circuit to generate a programming pulse. That's just insane! Anyway, there's bound to be reference programmer circuits for your AT89, so, really, go with those. Your programming data *comes from somewhere* and it should be easy to make that *somewhere* stick to the timing necessary. You need to do that, in the end, anyways.

Comment: Mike: It's probably a good idea to explain why you feel you cannot use software. You obviously have an OUT to trigger the circuit and another pin you can afford to use to set up the timing, too. Precisely WHY are you unable to handle the variable pulse width in software and save a pin and phase issues, and must instead build something with lots of extra hardware outside in order to get this working for you? To be honest, the only reason I can imagine right now is that you lack some basic software skills and feel forced to this. But perhaps you really do have a good reason. We should hear it.

Comment: I've used methods like that, to program UVerasable PROMs from National. Everyone was surprised such a beast would work. But instead of spending $5,000 for a programmer, my boss had me design/build it; I used MillerEffect capacitance to implement controlled-slew-rate programming edges. But, today, why not use a XTAL-stabilized MCU to produce pulses? The PWM outputs are configurable; you will need to bring ALL THE TIMING under control of the MCU, to avoid glitches.

Comment: Use a digital timer in your digital programmer for your digital microcontroller. I wouldn't necessarily use a microcontroller but, without seeing your programmer circuit design, I can't comment further on that. Nonetheless, make your life easier and use a digital timer of some form (74xx, CPLD, MCU etc.).

Comment: I updated my question and may have made a good timer. And I don't go for commercial programmers because they'll have specific software requirements which my computer probably can't handle.